# How can I use conditional logic on a full join (SQL)?

Tags: sql

I have two date fields (Outgoing Sample Date, Incoming Sample Date) in a table ("Table1").

I'm trying to join a few of the fields from this table to another table ("Table2"), which also has two date fields (Outgoing Sample Date, Incoming Sample Date).

I have the following SQL code running in Sisense:

```
Select CombinedTable.*
From    
(Select 
       coalesce(Table1.IncomingSampleDate, Table2.IncomingSampleDate) as "Final Incoming Date"
       coalesce(Table1.OutgoingSampleDate, Table2.OutgoingSampleDate) as "Final Outgoing Date"

From Table1 a
Full Join Table2 b on (coalesce(b.[IncomingSampleDate], b.[OutgoingSampleDate]))
)
As CombinedTable
```

However, I keep getting the following error when I include that last conditional on the full join:

"Object Reference not set to instance of an object"

There is no error when I run a simple full join on a.[IncomingSampleDate] = b.[IncomingSampleDate]

What does this error mean and how can I successfully introduce conditional logic into my full join?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A `full join` does not seem like a useful construct here.  And if you are using `full join`, you are not using MySQL, so I am removing that tag.

Comment: Sorry, running through Sisense. But the data Connectors and files are MySQL.

Comment: . . I have no idea what Sisense is doing but MySQL does not support `full join` nor does it support square braces in column names.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not implement `FULL OUTER JOIN`s.

Instead of doing the unsupported join:

```
select <columns>
from a
full join b on <predicate>
```

You can do:

```
select <columns>
from a
left join b on <predicate>
union
select <columns>
from b
left join a on <predicate>
```

A little bit verbose, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
on (coalesce(b.[IncomingSampleDate], b.[OutgoingSampleDate]))
```

This is not typically a valid join criteria. The statement evaluated to a date value instead of a boolean (True/False). Conditional logic is allowed in almost of SQL Variants in the join but as a general rule it must still return a boolean once it is evaluated (True/False).

```
 a.[IncomingSampleDate] = b.[IncomingSampleDate]
```

In a full outer that statement will return all rows in A and B that do not match as well as all rows that do match (*max cardinality detween the tables).

Notes are a generic SQL variant, I do not have a sisense system to test on this morning.